# Performance issue with joining tables over 3 DB links

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance, dblink

Recently we have faced the problem where we are fetching the data from 3 different data sources over a db link. It was running fine when we were fetching 16 columns from the tables by joining three sources. But as we increased the column from 16 to 50 the query is taking too much time.

Here we are fetching the data from 3 different data source  consider as A(Singapore), B(Malaysia), C (India) and and creating a view with the combination of above 3 regions and the view we have published to  the front -end team (Tableau team) to perform the visualization process over that data

Any suggestion how to solve the problem? I am planning for below alternatives

1. applying `/*+ DRIVING_SITE */` hint so that it run on remote server with the update statistics.
2. creating a MV on local server and refreshing the data over night, but it will not have proper update data.
3. creating a mv on local server and partitioning the mv and refreshing the partition whenever the changes  has occurred at remote site, so to alert for changes planning to create a queuing system or DBMS_PIPE if it helps.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: which approach i should follow or any other alternative to improve the performance ?

Comment: Copy the tables over, replicating them in some fashion.  Don't have Tableau hitting a view that hits multiple different servers if you want performance from the system.